# How to make this image responsive not fixed

Tags: image, formatting

I fetch an image using this syntax

'''''
echo "<img src="data:${fileData["MimeType"]};base64,${fileEncode}"/ height='350px' width='350px'";
''''

is there a way I can make this responsive using bootstrap?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just add class = "img-fluid" to the img tag.
according to Bootstrap documentation "Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with .img-fluid. This applies max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image so that it scales with the parent element.".

Comment: Faisal! Thank you so very much!  After experimenting to find the right way to add your answer I succeeded.   Here is the working code..  ''''''''''     echo @"<img src=\"data:${fileData["MimeType"]};base64,  ${fileEncode}  \" class=\"img-fluid\" "; //height='350px' width='350px'
''''''''  Thanks again!!